# Specify Foreign Key with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am using the newest version of ASP.NET Entity Framework Code First.

If I have two classes as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Classroom
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way for me to use Data Annotations so that when the Classroom table is generated, it knows that I want a ForeignKey to exist in Classroom called StudentID?  I know how to do it with FluentAPI, but if I could get it done with Data Annotations it would make my application much more simple.  I also would like to avoid having a separate StudentID property in the actual object model because it seems repetitive.

Comment: William,  Repetitive is the way to go in Entity Framework when establishing relationships.  It's better to have both an ID and an object per the EF guru Julie Lerman.  Maybe someone else can comment on the "why".

Comment: I have read somewhere that EF does something to keep these two I'm sync as well - do you know the details of this?  Is it done in the setters or only when changes to the database are committed?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Classroom
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but this uses the explicit int StudentId property - this seems like it is unnecessary - is there a way around using it or is there a reason that I should be using it?

Comment: See my comment above.  EF Code first has to guess less with the more information you provide.  Think about it...it's an Id property and you are working with database relationships...it's fundamental not unnecessary fluff. :) IMHO